# Displayed answer not consistent with edit mode

Tags: bug, editing, markdown

The post looks different when in edit mode with respect to how it looks once it is saved. See for example [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1236830/700617), and specifically the last two lines at the bottom.

In edit mode, I managed to display a single blank line between the two lines of code, but when the post was saved a larger (double) blank line appeared instead.

Edit mode:
[image]

Saved post:
[image]

I believe the preview and final version should be consistent, so I'd like to report this as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a single blank line between your two code lines you can separate them using:

```
<!-- comment -->
```

Followed by a blank line:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\0"} {match($0,/templateUrl: .*/,m); gsub("templateUrl: .*","templateUrl: templateUrl"); print "var "m[0]$0}' *
<!-- comment -->

awk -i '/templateUrl: / {a=$1" "$2;gsub("templateUrl: .*","templateUrl: templateUrl")} NR==1 {file=$0} NR==2{file=file"\n"$0} END{print a"\n"file}' *
```

This displays as:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\0"} {match($0,/templateUrl: .*/,m); gsub("templateUrl: .*","templateUrl: templateUrl"); print "var "m[0]$0}' *
```

```
awk -i '/templateUrl: / {a=$1" "$2;gsub("templateUrl: .*","templateUrl: templateUrl")} NR==1 {file=$0} NR==2{file=file"\n"$0} END{print a"\n"file}' *
```

I've updated your answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the workaround! Would you say this bug is not worth reporting?

Comment: @simlev I'd say it's worth reporting because the editor preview should show users how their post is going to look. It's very nice that there's a way to make the final version display as you want, but there's still a discrepancy between the preview and the final version.

Comment: @simlev I would leave it in case anyone else has the same issue. There are so many odd corner cases to markdown formatting that it is unlikely to get fixed soon.